# jQuery refresh div after .post completed

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

Is it possible to refresh a div once a piece of script has run?

I am trying to do a manual ranking system where items are listed but when I change the number in an input the following runs

**jQuery**

```
$('input.ranking').keyup(function(e) {
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var substr = thisClass.split('-');
        var pdID = substr[1];
        var pdRank = $(this).val();
        qString = 'pdID='+pdID+'&pdRank='+pdRank;
        if(typeof timeout != 'undefined') clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            //console.log(qString);
            $.post('/assets/inc/set-rank.php', qString, function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }, "json");

        }, 1000);
    });
```

This does't refresh the list or the page. Could someone assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$.post('/assets/inc/set-rank.php', function(data) {
  $('.yourDivClass').html(data);
});
```

Comment: this isnt writing my data to html. its not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a timeout, that's just....odd. You have the right idea, just needs some refinement. The logic goes like this: on keyup send an ajax post then take results and display it. JSON isn't needed unless the results are in JSON format. If it is then you'll need to modify the displayed data.

Non-JSON:

```
$('input.ranking').keyup(function(e) {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var substr = thisClass.split('-');
    var pdID = substr[1];
    var pdRank = $(this).val();
    qString = 'pdID=' + pdID + '&pdRank=' + pdRank;
    $.post('/assets/inc/set-rank.php', qString, function(data) {
        $('#display-div').html(data);
    });
});​
```

JSON:

```
$('input.ranking').keyup(function(e) {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var substr = thisClass.split('-');
    var pdID = substr[1];
    var pdRank = $(this).val();
    qString = 'pdID=' + pdID + '&pdRank=' + pdRank;
    $.post('/assets/inc/set-rank.php', qString, function(data) {
        $('#display-div').html(data.results);
    }, "json");
});​
```